# Regex for Range $5,000 - $1,000,000 (with commas and dollar sign optional)

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need help creating a regex a number range of 4,000-1,000,000 with the commas and dollar sign being optional to the user.

I'm trying to annotate validation for a departments budget using asp.net with a regular expression or custom validator that permits an optional dollar sign and commas with the range from $5000.00 to $1,000,000

```
^\$?([5-9][0-9]{3,5}|1000000)$
```

Sadly, this didn't work it's what I came up with, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Generally "optional" translates into things like `1,?000,?000` instead.

Comment: @tadman Yes I know that and also I'd have to do \,? but the problem is figuring out how to do the full regex. I'm not wellversed only done it a couple times.

Comment: `,` isn't a special character, so there's no need for the backslash. Why are you using a regular expression to match this? Do you need the commas to be in precisely the right spot, or is `1,000,00` still valid?

Comment: @tadman It was requested and yes it does as it is money. So it needs to be $5,000 - $1,000,000 with the money sign and commas being optional. But no 1,000,00 wouldn't be correct. 10,000 is how it is formatted. As with how currency would normally put a , for cash. It depends on the amount of 0's where the commas go.

Comment: "Normally" is a highly subjective thing, as each country in the world has its own quirky standards. "$3,99" isn't out of the question in some places. Can you give a few cases of good input, and bad input that should be rejected? It's not clear from your short description how robust this has to be.

Comment: @tadman Very true. My mistake, im going by North America (Canada, ON)

Comment: Heh, I know what you're saying but Mexico and Québec are both in North America and have different ideas of "normal".

Comment: @tadman GOOD - 5,000 : 50,000 : 500,000 : 1,000,000 BAD - 5,0000 : 5,000,0 : 5,000,00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is definitely a solid choice, but if you notice the ending you could do it a more simple way being that of the second one down below with ,? to make it shorter in length.

```
^(?:5,?\d{3}|[6-9],?\d{3}|[1-9]\d{1,2},?\d{3}|1,000,000|1000000)$
```

VS

```
^\$?([5-9],?\d{3}|\d{2,3}?,?\d{3}|(?:1,?000,?000))$
```

The second one is a lot cleaner and from what I can tell works fully.

Comment: You can combine these `5,?\d{3}|[6-9],?\d{3}`

Answer (score 2):

```
^\$?(?:[5-9],?\d{3}|[1-9]\d{1,2},?\d{3}|1,000,000|1000000)$
```

Comment: Matches `1,000000`

Comment: I believe if you wanted to force consistency with comma usage it would be: ^\$?([5-9],?\d{3}|\d{2,3}?,?\d{3}|1,000,000|1000000))$

Comment: Now would ^\$?([5-9],?\d{3}|\d{2,3}?,?\d{3}|1,000,000|1000000))$ or ^\$?(?:[5-9],?\d{3}|[1-9]\d{1,2},?\d{3}|1,000,000|1000000)$ work better?

Comment: You want ^(?:[5-9],?\d{3}|[1-9]\d{1,2},?\d{3}|1,000,000|1000000)$, this answer matches: 000,000

Answer (score 1):

***edit:*** add the optional dollar sign `\$?`

`^(?:[5-9],?\d{3}|[1-9]\d{1,2},?\d{3}|1,000,000|1000000)$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      [5-9] ,? \d{3} 
   |  [1-9] \d{1,2} ,? \d{3} 
   |  1, 000 , 000
   |  1  000   000
 )
 $
```